# How to get email id of configured mail in my app in iOS

Tags: iphone, email, ios7

Is it possible to get email id of conjured mail in iPhone? if yes then how? I searched on stack overflow and googled and i got that there is no documented api to get email id of mail configured but i want to access, is there any way to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API to get a user's email address or any information about any email accounts they have setup. You have to ask the user.

All the best

Comment: Thanks for confirmation